# updating account balance with django

Tags: django

absolute n00b here, just fiddling around. Trying to make a very simple app to track my personal expenses. I have a class for entering the expenses, a class for the categories and a class for my account balance. Plan is to create en entry in the account balance everytime I create an expense.

How do I update my account balance? I'll have to get fields from the latest entry in expenses to do the math with in my balance class, right?

This is what I have. Any help appreciated.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Balance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    previous_balance = ????
    transaction = ????
    current_balance = previous_balance - transaction


class Expense(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    spender = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,default=1)
    ABN = 'ABN'
    ING = 'ING'
    ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
        (ABN, 'ABN'),
        (ING, 'ING'),
    )
    account = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES,
        default=ABN,
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def commit(self):
        self.commit_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s. Kosten: %s" % (self.description, self.amount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considered balance change will be trigger by expense record change, you can overwrite save on Expense model. then balance table can be maintain in auto.

import datetime

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    spender = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,default=1)
    ABN = 'ABN'
    ING = 'ING'
    ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
        (ABN, 'ABN'),
        (ING, 'ING'),
    )
    account = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES,
        default=ABN,
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Expense, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        last_bal = Balance.objects.order_by('id').last()
        Balance.objects.create(date=datetime.datetime.now(), previouse_balance=last_bal.current_balance,
                               transaction=self, current_balance=last_bal.current_balance + self.amount)
```

Comment: But not very clear why do you need a new model Balance, just add a balance field on Expense should be easiler if Expense model covered all types of transactions.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. And yes, it probably would be easier to have a balance field on my Expenses model. But I worry that in the end it might prove useful to have a model with records just for the balance. But maybe that's just too much thinking ahead.

In the case of making a balance field could I get the last record by using
last_bal = Expense.objects.order_by('id').last()
Or would that return the Expense record i was just creating?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to get your current balance after creating Expenses. If so, you can use [Django's aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Balance(models.Model):
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   # Keep the amount you start with
   starting_balance = models.IntegerField()

   # Get the Sum of all expenses and do some simple subtraction
   def get_current_balance(self):
       total_expenses = Expense.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('amount'))
       return self.starting_balance - total_expenses['amount__sum']
```

Then in your views, you can do something like:

`current_balance = some_balance_instance.get_current_balance()`